# UPS Bill to Third Party Shipper?

Tags: php, api, ups

I'm trying to figure out how to bill a third party UPS Shipper Account Number using the API, When I try what I have listed below it doesn't work! It says "A single billing option is required per shipment" in the error message.  Anyone have any idea whats wrong?

```
$ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->push('PaymentInformation');
                $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->push('Prepaid');
                    $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->push('BillThirdParty');
                            $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->element('AccountNumber', 'XXXXX');
                    $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->pop(); // end BillShipper 
                $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->pop(); // end Prepaid
            $ShipmentConfirmRequestXML->pop(); // end PaymentInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Third party billing is not within the Prepaid container.  The end result XML should look something like this, based on the UPS API developers guide:

```
<PaymentInformation>
    <BillThirdParty>
        <BillThirdPartyShipper>
            <AccountNumber>ABC123</AccountNumber>
            <ThirdParty>
                <Address>
                    <PostalCode>12345-6789</PostalCode>
                    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                </Address>
            </ThirdParty>
        </BillThirdPartyShipper>
    </BillThirdParty>
</PaymentInformation>
```

For some reason, the UPS API will always fail with third party billing in test mode, giving a Transient 120001 error, "XML Shipping System is unavailable, please try again later".  Switching off test mode fixes the problem - just void the shipment after you've confirmed your code works.

Also, if you ever enter an incorrect account code for third party billing, the same 120001 error will be returned.